# Convert unidirectional LSTM cell to Bidirectinoal LSTM cell in tensorflow 1.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, lstm

I have this legacy code that was inmplemented in tensorflow 1.0.1.
I want to convert the current LSTM cell to bidirrectional LSTM.

```
with tf.variable_scope("encoder_scope") as encoder_scope:

cell = contrib_rnn.LSTMCell(num_units=state_size, state_is_tuple=True)
cell = DtypeDropoutWrapper(cell=cell, output_keep_prob=tf_keep_probabiltiy, dtype=DTYPE)
cell = contrib_rnn.MultiRNNCell(cells=[cell] * num_lstm_layers, state_is_tuple=True)

encoder_cell = cell

encoder_outputs, last_encoder_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
    cell=encoder_cell,
    dtype=DTYPE,
    sequence_length=encoder_sequence_lengths,
    inputs=encoder_inputs,
    )
```

I found some examples out there.
https://riptutorial.com/tensorflow/example/17004/creating-a-bidirectional-lstm

But I cannot convert my LSTM cell to bidirectional LSTM cell by reffering them.
What should be put into **state_below** in my case?

**Update**: Apart from above issue I need to clarify how to convert following decoder network (dynamic_rnn_decoder) to use bidirectional LSTM. (The documentation does not give any clue about that)

```
with tf.variable_scope("decoder_scope") as decoder_scope:

    decoder_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_units=state_size)
    decoder_cell = DtypeDropoutWrapper(cell=decoder_cell, output_keep_prob=tf_keep_probabiltiy, dtype=DTYPE)
    decoder_cell = contrib_rnn.MultiRNNCell(cells=[decoder_cell] * num_lstm_layers, state_is_tuple=True)   

    # define decoder train netowrk
    decoder_outputs_tr, _ , _ = dynamic_rnn_decoder(
        cell=decoder_cell, # the cell function
        decoder_fn= simple_decoder_fn_train(last_encoder_state, name=None),
        inputs=decoder_inputs,
        sequence_length=decoder_sequence_lengths,
        parallel_iterations=None,
        swap_memory=False,
        time_major=False)
```

Can anyone please clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use bidirectional_dynamic_rnn [[1]](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/nn/bidirectional_dynamic_rnn)

```
cell_fw = contrib_rnn.LSTMCell(num_units=state_size, state_is_tuple=True)
cell_fw = DtypeDropoutWrapper(cell=cell_fw, output_keep_prob=tf_keep_probabiltiy, dtype=DTYPE)
cell_fw = contrib_rnn.MultiRNNCell(cells=[cell_fw] * int(num_lstm_layers/2), state_is_tuple=True)

cell_bw = contrib_rnn.LSTMCell(num_units=state_size, state_is_tuple=True)
cell_bw = DtypeDropoutWrapper(cell=cell_bw, output_keep_prob=tf_keep_probabiltiy, dtype=DTYPE)
cell_bw = contrib_rnn.MultiRNNCell(cells=[cell_bw] * num_lstm_layers, state_is_tuple=True)

encoder_cell_fw = cell_fw
encoder_cell_bw = cell_bw

encoder_outputs, (output_state_fw, output_state_bw) = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(
    cell_fw=encoder_cell_fw,
    cell_bw=encoder_cell_bw,
    dtype=DTYPE,
    sequence_length=encoder_sequence_lengths,
    inputs=encoder_inputs,
    )

last_encoder_state = [
                       tf.concat([output_state_fw[0], output_state_bw[0]], axis=-1),
                       tf.concat([output_state_fw[1], output_state_bw[1]], axis=-1)
                     ]
```

However, as it says in TensorFlow docs, this API is deprecated and you should consider moving to TensorFlow2 and use `keras.layers.Bidirectional(keras.layers.RNN(cell))`

Regarding the updated question, you cannot use bidirectional in the decoder model as bidirectional would mean it already knew what it still has to generate [[2]](https://github.com/rstudio/keras/issues/624#issuecomment-450792167)

Anyway, to adapt your decoder to the bidirectional encoder you could concatenate the encoder states and double the decoder num_units (or half the num_units in the encoder) [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50815354/seq2seq-bidirectional-encoder-decoder-in-keras)

```
decoder_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_units=state_size)
decoder_cell = DtypeDropoutWrapper(cell=decoder_cell, output_keep_prob=tf_keep_probabiltiy, dtype=DTYPE)
decoder_cell = contrib_rnn.MultiRNNCell(cells=[decoder_cell] * num_lstm_layers, state_is_tuple=True)   

# define decoder train netowrk
decoder_outputs_tr, _ , _ = dynamic_rnn_decoder(
    cell=decoder_cell, # the cell function
    decoder_fn= simple_decoder_fn_train(last_encoder_state, name=None),
    inputs=decoder_inputs,
    sequence_length=decoder_sequence_lengths,
    parallel_iterations=None,
    swap_memory=False,
    time_major=False)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your support. But I failed to mansion another part of the same encoder-decoder network that need to be converted to biLSTM. Could you please help me out in updated question?

Comment: Thanks, but the tf.concat requires an axis to do concatiation. According to your code what whould be the correct axis to be given?

Comment: I used axis = 1, by following https://github.com/Scitator/YATS2S/blob/versions/tf_1.2/seq2seq/rnn_encoder.py#L91. but decoder outputs does not have correct shape to  be trained using loss functoin I use. I think it should also be concatenated to get the original shape so that the loss function I use work correctly. Can you help me how to do that?

Comment: Try using axis=-1